# D3 barchart using external data

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I made a bar chart using d3.js v4 and im trying to use external data file (.tsv) file and it  gives me the following error: Error:  attribute height: Expected length, "NaN". (anonymous) @ d3.min.js:2 o @ d3.min.js:2 yn @ d3.min.js:2 mn @ d3.min.js:2 d3.min.js:2 Error:  attribute y: Expected length, "NaN".

here is my code:

```js
var bardata = [];

d3.tsv('data.tsv', function(data){

    for (key in data){
        bardata.push(data[key].value)
  }
    
    
    var margin = {top:30, right:30, bottom:40, left:50}

var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
  barWidth = 50,
  barOffset = 5;
var tempColor;

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(bardata)])
  .range([0, height]);

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(0, bardata.length))
  .padding(0.1)
  .range([0, width]);

var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
.style('position', 'absolute')
.style('padding', '0 10px')
.style('background', 'white')
.style('opacity', 0)

var myChart = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
.style('background', '#E7E0CB')
  .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate('+ margin.left +', '+ margin.top +')')
  .style('background', '#C9D7D6')
  .selectAll('rect').data(bardata)
  .enter().append('rect')
  .style('fill', '#C61C6F')
  .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
  

.attr('x', function(d, i) {
    return xScale(i);
  })
.attr('height', 0)
.attr('y', height)

.on('mouseover', function(d){
    d3.select(this)
    .style('opacity', 0.5)
})
.on('mouseleave', function(d){
    d3.select(this)
    .style('opacity', 1)
})
.on('mouseover', function(d){
    tooltip.transition()
    .style('opacity', 0.9)
    tooltip.html(d)
    .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 35) + 'px')
    .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 30) + 'px')
    
    tempColor = this.style.fill;
    d3.select(this)
    .style('opacity', 0.5)
    .style('fill', 'yellow')
})
.on('mouseleave', function(d){
    tempColor = this.style.fill;
    d3.select(this)
    .style('opacity', 1)
    .style('fill', '#C61C6F')
})

myChart.transition()
.attr('height', function(d){
    return yScale(d);
})
.attr('y', function(d){
    return height - yScale(d);
})
.delay(function(d, i){
    return i * 20;
})
.duration(1000)
.ease(d3.easeElastic)

var vGuideScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(bardata)])
  .range([0, height]);

var vAxis = d3.axisLeft(vGuideScale).ticks(10)

var vGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g')
vAxis(vGuide)

vGuide.attr('transform', 'translate('+ margin.left +', '+ margin.top +')')

var hAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickValues(xScale.domain().filter(function(d,i){
    return !(i % (bardata.length/5))
}))

var hGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g')
hAxis(hGuide)

hGuide.attr('transform', 'translate('+ margin.left +', '+ (height + margin.top) +')')

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Line Chart</title>
    <meta charset="8-UTF">
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="css/style.css"> </head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Bar Chart</h2>
       <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is my data.tsv 
value
23
22
24
23
27
26
30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
var myChart = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
    .style('background', '#E7E0CB')
    .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')')
    .style('background', '#C9D7D6')
    .selectAll('rect').data(bardata)
    .enter().append('rect')
    .style('fill', '#C61C6F')
    .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
```

In one single variable, you are:

1. appending an SVG
2. appending a group
3. creating an enter selection
4. appending the rectangles

Instead of that, let's break that variable:

```
var myChart = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .style('background', '#E7E0CB')
    .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')')
    .style('background', '#C9D7D6');

var rects = myChart.selectAll('rect').data(bardata)
    .enter().append('rect')
    .style('fill', '#C61C6F')
    .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr('x', function(d, i) {
        return xScale(i);
    })
    .attr('height', 0)
    .attr('y', height)
```

Then, you call the transition on `rects` alone.

Besides that, mind the `columns` property, which is automatically created by `d3.tsv`:

```
for (key in data) {
    if (key != "columns") bardata.push(data[key].value)
}
```

Here is your working code:

```js
var bardata = [];

var data = d3.tsvParse(d3.select("#tsv").text());

for (key in data) {
  if (key != "columns") bardata.push(data[key].value)
}

var margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 30,
  bottom: 40,
  left: 50
}

var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
  barWidth = 50,
  barOffset = 5;
var tempColor;

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(bardata)])
  .range([0, height]);

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(0, bardata.length))
  .padding(0.1)
  .range([0, width]);

var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
  .style('position', 'absolute')
  .style('padding', '0 10px')
  .style('background', 'white')
  .style('opacity', 0)

var myChart = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .style('background', '#E7E0CB')
  .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')')
  .style('background', '#C9D7D6');

var rects = myChart.selectAll('rect').data(bardata)
  .enter().append('rect')
  .style('fill', '#C61C6F')
  .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr('x', function(d, i) {
    return xScale(i);
  })
  .attr('height', 0)
  .attr('y', height)

.on('mouseover', function(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .style('opacity', 0.5)
  })
  .on('mouseleave', function(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .style('opacity', 1)
  })
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    tooltip.transition()
      .style('opacity', 0.9)
    tooltip.html(d)
      .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 35) + 'px')
      .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 30) + 'px')

    tempColor = this.style.fill;
    d3.select(this)
      .style('opacity', 0.5)
      .style('fill', 'yellow')
  })
  .on('mouseleave', function(d) {
    tempColor = this.style.fill;
    d3.select(this)
      .style('opacity', 1)
      .style('fill', '#C61C6F')
  })

rects.transition()
  .attr('height', function(d) {
    return yScale(d);
  })
  .attr('y', function(d) {
    return height - yScale(d);
  })
  .delay(function(d, i) {
    return i * 20;
  })
  .duration(1000)
  .ease(d3.easeElastic)

var vGuideScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(bardata)])
  .range([0, height]);

var vAxis = d3.axisLeft(vGuideScale).ticks(10)

var vGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g')
vAxis(vGuide)

vGuide.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')')

var hAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickValues(xScale.domain().filter(function(d, i) {
  return !(i % (bardata.length / 5))
}))

var hGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g')
hAxis(hGuide)

hGuide.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + (height + margin.top) + ')');
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="tsv">value
23
22
24
23
27
26
30
</pre>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null
it gives me the above error

Comment: I'm not following this, can you explain?

Comment: i copied your code and it gave this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null"

Comment: Well, you can see that my code, which is an **exact** copy of yours with those changes only, is working. Did you change the `for...in` loop?

Comment: **How** did you copied my code? Did you copy the entire snippet? Pay attention that I'm using `d3.tsvParse` in the snippet, which parses a `<pre>` element that doesn't exist in your code. You're probably copying that part (`var data = d3.tsvParse(d3.select("#tsv").text());`), which will give you an error, since you don't have that `<pre>` in your code. Please, change **only** the parts I mention in my answer.