# Load external data (.tsv) into d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I'm working on d3.js v4 and im trying to load external data from data.tsv file but its not loading, here is my code:

```js
var bardata = [];

d3.tsv('data.tsv', function(){
    
    for (key in data){
        bardata.push(data[key].year.value)
    }
    
    var margin = {top:30, right:30, bottom:40, left:50}

var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
  barWidth = 50,
  barOffset = 5;
var tempColor;

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(bardata)])
  .range([0, height]);

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(0, bardata.length))
  .padding(0.1)
  .range([0, width]);

var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
.style('position', 'absolute')
.style('padding', '0 10px')
.style('background', 'white')
.style('opacity', 0)

var myChart = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
.style('background', '#E7E0CB')
  .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate('+ margin.left +', '+ margin.top +')')
  .style('background', '#C9D7D6')
  .selectAll('rect').data(bardata)
  .enter().append('rect')
  .style('fill', '#C61C6F')
  .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
  

.attr('x', function(d, i) {
    return xScale(i);
  })
.attr('height', 0)
.attr('y', height)

.on('mouseover', function(d){
    d3.select(this)
    .style('opacity', 0.5)
})
.on('mouseleave', function(d){
    d3.select(this)
    .style('opacity', 1)
})
.on('mouseover', function(d){
    tooltip.transition()
    .style('opacity', 0.9)
    tooltip.html(d)
    .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 35) + 'px')
    .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 30) + 'px')
    
    tempColor = this.style.fill;
    d3.select(this)
    .style('opacity', 0.5)
    .style('fill', 'yellow')
})
.on('mouseleave', function(d){
    tempColor = this.style.fill;
    d3.select(this)
    .style('opacity', 1)
    .style('fill', '#C61C6F')
})

myChart.transition()
.attr('height', function(d){
    return yScale(d);
})
.attr('y', function(d){
    return height - yScale(d);
})
.delay(function(d, i){
    return i * 20;
})
.duration(1000)
.ease(d3.easeElastic)

var vGuideScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(bardata)])
  .range([0, height]);

var vAxis = d3.axisLeft(vGuideScale).ticks(10)

var vGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g')
vAxis(vGuide)

vGuide.attr('transform', 'translate('+ margin.left +', '+ margin.top +')')

var hAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickValues(xScale.domain().filter(function(d,i){
    return !(i % (bardata.length/5))
}))

var hGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g')
hAxis(hGuide)

hGuide.attr('transform', 'translate('+ margin.left +', '+ (height + margin.top) +')')

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bar Chart</title>
    <meta charset="8-UTF">
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="css/style.css"> </head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Bar Chart</h2>
       <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is the data in my tsv file

```
year value
2010 23,499,201
2011 22,544,175
2012 24,061,655
2013 23,413,369
2014 27,144,494
2015 26,812,665
2016 30,377,832
```

its has no errors but nothing appears on the chart

Comment: Before I close this question: how is this different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808590/d3-barchart-using-external-data)?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado i have multiple values in my tsv file and its loading anything the whole chart disappears

Comment: your callback function needs to have a parameter,
`d3.tsv('data.tsv', function(data){`

Comment: Do what user3821538 just said and, besides, format your TSV accordingly in the question: it's impossible to see any tab.

Comment: @user3821538 i tried that it didnt work

Comment: @GerardoFurtado its formatted properly but its messed here in the comment and data parameter didn't work

Comment: I mean please format it properly **in the question**. It's impossible to help you if you don't format it properly. For instance, I'm seeing 1 year per row but 3 values per row. Where are the values headers? The errors become clear if you properly format the TSV.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado it has two columns which are year and value, the year column is from 2010 - 2016, and the value column contains one value only like 23,499,201 this is one large number not multiple values

Comment: try `d3.tsv('data.tsv', function(error, data){` instead, and instead of doing `data[key].year.value`, it should be selecting one or the other of either `year` or `value`, both won't bring back anything. `data.foreach(function(d)  { bardata.push([d.year, d.value]) })` would be best. No need to specify a key since you aren't using it for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're trying to create your bar chart right now, getting rid of the nice array of objects `d3.tsv` creates for you and relying in a simple array of numbers, **is not** the adequate let alone the most convenient way to do it. For any seasoned D3 coder, it makes little sense. However, it's not my place giving lectures here.

That being said, I'll address only the current problems:

1. `d3.tsv` needs a parameter in the callback:

   ```
   d3.tsv('data.tsv', function(data){
   //parameter here -------------^
   ```
2. Don't put comma in your numbers. This is not accepted in any programming language I'm aware of:

   ```
   23,499,201 ---> 23499201
   ```
3. Remember, as I said in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42808590/5768908), to avoid the `columns` property:

   ```
   for (key in data) {
       if (key != "columns") bardata.push(data[key].value)
   }
   ```
4. Convert the strings to numbers:

   ```
   bardata.push(+data[key].value)
   ```

All together, this is your working code:

```js
var data = d3.tsvParse(d3.select("#tsv").text());

var bardata = [];
    
    for (key in data){
        if(key != "columns") bardata.push(+data[key].value)
    }
    
    var margin = {top:30, right:30, bottom:40, left:50}

var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
  barWidth = 50,
  barOffset = 5;
var tempColor;

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(bardata)])
  .range([0, height]);

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(0, bardata.length))
  .padding(0.1)
  .range([0, width]);

var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
.style('position', 'absolute')
.style('padding', '0 10px')
.style('background', 'white')
.style('opacity', 0)

var myChart = d3.select('body').append('svg')
.style('background', '#E7E0CB')
  .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate('+ margin.left +', '+ margin.top +')')
  .style('background', '#C9D7D6')
  .selectAll('rect').data(bardata)
  .enter().append('rect')
  .style('fill', '#C61C6F')
  .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
  

.attr('x', function(d, i) {
    return xScale(i);
  })
.attr('height', 0)
.attr('y', height)

.on('mouseover', function(d){
    d3.select(this)
    .style('opacity', 0.5)
})
.on('mouseleave', function(d){
    d3.select(this)
    .style('opacity', 1)
})
.on('mouseover', function(d){
    tooltip.transition()
    .style('opacity', 0.9)
    tooltip.html(d)
    .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 35) + 'px')
    .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 30) + 'px')
    
    tempColor = this.style.fill;
    d3.select(this)
    .style('opacity', 0.5)
    .style('fill', 'yellow')
})
.on('mouseleave', function(d){
    tempColor = this.style.fill;
    d3.select(this)
    .style('opacity', 1)
    .style('fill', '#C61C6F')
})

myChart.transition()
.attr('height', function(d){
    return yScale(d);
})
.attr('y', function(d){
    return height - yScale(d);
})
.delay(function(d, i){
    return i * 20;
})
.duration(1000)
.ease(d3.easeElastic)

var vGuideScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(bardata)])
  .range([0, height]);

var vAxis = d3.axisLeft(vGuideScale).ticks(10)

var vGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g')
vAxis(vGuide)

vGuide.attr('transform', 'translate('+ margin.left +', '+ margin.top +')')

var hAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickValues(xScale.domain().filter(function(d,i){
    return !(i % (bardata.length/5))
}))

var hGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g')
hAxis(hGuide)

hGuide.attr('transform', 'translate('+ margin.left +', '+ (height + margin.top) +')')
```

```css
pre{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="tsv">year value
2010 23499201
2011 22544175
2012 24061655
2013 23413369
2014 27144494
2015 26812665
2016 30377832
</pre>
```

Again: I'm using a `<pre>` element to store the data. Don't simply copy/paste my snippet, as you did [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808590/d3-barchart-using-external-data#comment72730850_42808829).